# Install tensorflow in editable mode

Tags: tensorflow, installation

I would like to contribute to the project tensorflow. To do so, I would like to install tensorflow in editable mode. Does someone know how to do it ?

Many thanks !

Comment: It shouldn't differ from any other open source project on github. Here is a nice doc  https://akrabat.com/the-beginners-guide-to-contributing-to-a-github-project/

Comment: What is specific is I would like to install the package (python part of the project) in editable mode so that I can easily see my changes

Answer (score 0):

I found it by a simple windows search.

For me it was in `C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\tf dev\tensorflow\tensorflow\tools\pip_package`

For you it will be in `directory in which cloned tensorflow is\tensorflow\tensorflow\tools\pip_package`.

`tf dev` is where my virtualenv and cloned repo is.

**Code that I used**

```
(venv) C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\tf dev>pip install -e "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\tf dev\tensorflow\tensorflow\tools\pip_package"

Obtaining file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/tf%20dev/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/pip_package
```